# CTCallCenter is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios10, core-telephony, callkit

I am using [`CTCallCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/ctcallcenter?language=objc) in my project. Now it's deprecated, I would like to know what are alternatives? How to get the event for the voice call?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is poorly documented, but I've found this mention in `CTCallCenter` public header files:

> "Replaced by `<CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>`"

So, from iOS 10 you should use [`CXCallObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxcallobserver) class of new [`CallKit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) framework to retrieve info about active calls:

```
CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
```

Provide object, conforming to [`CXCallObserverDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxcallobserverdelegate?language=objc) protocol and queue, on which you want to perform delegate callbacks:

```
// If queue is nil, then callbacks will be performed on main queue
[callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
// Don't forget to store reference to callObserver, to prevent it from being released
self.callObserver = callObserver;
```

and implement the following method on your delegate object:

```
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.hasConnected) {
        // perform necessary actions
    }
}
```

For more information, you can check:

- [Enhancing VoIP Apps with CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/) session from WWDC 2016
- [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project

Comment: for the swift 3+ users solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469336/7230057

Comment: This solution works fine for Forground app state but not Background, any solution for Background state?