# iOS 10 : How can I get a call event using CallKit/CXCallObserver?

Tags: objective-c, ios10, callkit

I changed the CTCallCenter with CXCallObserver in iOS 10.

Here is my code:

```
#import <CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>
#import <CallKit/CXCall.h>

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
    [callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    ... ...
}

- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.hasConnected) {
        NSLog(@"********** voice call connected **********/n");        
    } else if(call.hasEnded) {
        NSLog(@"********** voice call disconnected **********/n");        
    }
}
```

But I can't get a voice call event and I got a warning like this:

```
Sending 'HomeViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<CXCallObserverDelegate> _Nullable
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the CXCallObserverDelegate.

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <CXCallObserverDelegate>

@end
```

Then the warning will disappear and you get a voice call event.
I hope this help you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to store strong reference to `callObserver`, so it won't be released too early:

```
@interface YourClass ()<CXCallObserverDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallObserver *callObserver;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
    [callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.callObserver = callObserver;
}
```

For more information, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39911392/1948606) answer.